# macbook pro gpu isssue

Tags: graphics-card, macbook, gpu

I am also the victim of macbook pro discrete gpu issue. I bought this macbook pro from my colleague. After a usage of 9 months its behaving odd. I have found that this mac has the discrete gpu issue. I have also installed gfxcontrol. my concerns are the following.

- I cant buy a new macbook, financial issue.
- I am a developer can i use this mac with integrated gpu for xcode,simulator and web surfing(using chrome).
- Does it affect the mac if i use continuously the integrated gpu for the future.

I really need some guide line.Can i use this mac with integrated gpu taking care, like don't use those applications which use discrete gpu.

Thanks

Comment: Define "behaving odd". Unless you are playing games or something else that is graphically intense, the power management of the laptop should always have the integrated GPU being used (IE: Using Chrome).

Comment: i dont play games at all.just web surfing and lately i used adobe suite. Behaving odd , shutting off randomly, really hot underneath the keyboard, distorted display and black screen on startup. dont boot up

Comment: Can any one help me with this?